# Cannot connect to sql server by IP Address but using the hostname works

Tags: networking, sql-server, windows-10

After upgrading to the newest version of windows (windows 10 build 10586) I am no longer able to connect to a remote sql server by ip address.

Here is the error I see:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout
>   period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake
>   acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed
>   or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent
>   while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login]
>   initialization=18303; handshake=14385; ]

This is not a named instance of sql server.  I am able to connect without an issue if i use the hostname of the machine.  What could cause this?

On Windows 10 before the November update there was no problem connecting.

Sql Server 2012 (11.0.5058)
Windows 10 Build 10586

Comment: Any time I see something that acts differently with a name and an IP address, I assume authentication/kerberos issues. I don't know enough about sql to help though.

Comment: Are you sure hostname resolves to that ip address and not to some other maybe internal or ipv6 ip?

Comment: yeah, to be sure i disabled ipv6 on all network interfaces on my machine.  same issue.